# probabilisticsamplerprocessor gives confusing result

Tags: open-telemetry-collector, otel

I am trying to control the percentage of logs that will be shipped to the backend. I am using [probabilisticsamplerprocessor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/probabilisticsamplerprocessor). Considering that there is no change in the amount of total logs in the cluster. I am using the following config

```
      probabilistic_sampler/logs:
        hash_seed: 22
        sampling_percentage: 98
        attribute_source: record
        from_attribute: "k8s.cluster.name"
```

With this config, I get around 1.8K logs in Datadog dashbaord. Now, I gradually reduce the **sampling_percentage** from 98 to 90, 80, 70, 65, 60. But in Datadog I see so significant effect of this sampling until **sampling_percentage** 65 and the total amount of logs stays the same. However, when I set **sampling_percentage** to **60**, there are no logs available in the backend(in my case Datadog). I tried the following two configs as well

```
  probabilistic_sampler/logs:
    hash_seed: 22
    sampling_percentage: 98
```

My log pipeline in otel collector is as below

```
    logs/datadog:
      exporters:
      - debug
      - datadog
      processors:
      - resource/common
      - k8sattributes
      - memory_limiter
      - probabilistic_sampler/logs
      - batch/logs
      - transform/filelog_labels
      receivers:
      - filelog
```

Can anyone please explain, why the **sampling_percentage** does not have any significant effect and why log completely stops after **sampling_percentage: 60**?